# Python For Loop from How to think like a computer scientist

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I stumbled upon a new exercise in "How to Think like a Computer Scientist". (Open documentation @ http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch07.html)

Hope to receive some directions on this:

```
prefix="JKLMNOPQ"
suffix="ack"

for letter in prefix:
    print letter + suffix
```

and you get 
Jack, Kack, Lack, Mack, Nack, Oack, Pack & Qack.

What should I modify so that instead of Oack and Qack, I get Ouack and Quack?

For the sake of learning, what I attempted was:

```
prefix="JKLMNOPQ"
suffix="ack"

for letter in prefix:
  if letter = "O" or "U":
    print letter + "u" + suffix
  else:
    print letter + suffix
```

As most of you would notice at first sight, the syntax error committed is in using = instead of == in the if function call.

Thanks for all your prompt assistance, I greatly appreciate them.

Comment: You should accept some answers from past questions.

Comment: I rewrote the code and added if function call after the print letter + suffix. turns out that its a syntax error. my bad.

Comment: think about "if letter is O or Q, then print letter+u+suffix, otherwise just print letter+suffix"

Comment: Your SyntaxError is because you're using `=` (assignment) when you should be using `==` (equality)

Comment: -1.  You need to accept answers, not just edit the question.

Comment: @somekittens and how do you do that? I've already upvoted the correct answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given example relies on the fact that when iterated, a string gives each of its individual characters. Since you want some of your prefixes to have two characters, you have to break up your string into a separate one for each of the characters and add the `u` where you want it.

```
prefixes=["J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "Ou", "P", "Qu"]
suffix="ack"

for letters in prefixes:
    print letters + suffix
```

Answer (score 4):

I won't solve this for you, but will give you a hint: [the `if` statement](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch04.html#index-2) might come in handy.

Comment: I did that originally; turns out that i committed a syntax error. Pardons for the post.

Comment: @JasonHJH: If you've tried something and it didn't work, you have to post what you tried and how it didn't work. Otherwise we'll probably just tell you what didn't work.

Comment: You are not following the OP's original code design lines. @Levon 's answer _does_.

Answer (score 2):

```
prefix = "JKLMNOPQ"
suffix = "ack"

for letter in prefix:
    if letter == 'O' or letter == 'Q':
      print "".join((letter, 'u', suffix))
    else:
      print "".join((letter, suffix))



Jack
Kack
Lack
Mack
Nack
Ouack
Pack
Quack
```

Comment: Why `"".join([..])` and not `a+b+c`?

Answer (score 2):

Look for the two prefixes (Q and O), then add the 'u', otherwise just print as before

```
for letter in prefix:
   if letter in ['Q', 'O']:
      print letter + 'u' + suffix
   else:
      print letter + suffix
```

yields:

```
Jack
Kack
Lack
Mack
Nack
Ouack
Pack
Quack
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is regex solution:

```
import re
prefix="JKLMNOPQ"
suffix="ack"
names=[re.sub("([OQ])","\\1u",p) + suffix for p in prefixes]
print "\n".join(names)
```

I think the problem specified is to correct the input, i.e. it's not a question about how the input sucks and should be of the form ["J","K","L","M","N","Ou","P","Qu"] or whatever. Typically a regex substitution can be a good way of fixing string input.
If you intend to "think more like a computer scientist" I also recommend trying to use list comprehensions as much as possible to get the hang of them, and treat output as a separate concern.

Answer (score 0):

Using map function and regex

```
RX = lambda x: re.sub("(O|Q)","\\1u",x)
map(RX,[x+suffix for x in prefix])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
prefixes = 'JKLMNOPQ'
suffix = 'ack'


for letter in prefixes:
    while True:
        if letter == 'O':
            print letter + 'u' + suffix
            break
        if letter == 'Q':
            print 'Quack' # just another solution of the print statement
            break
        print letter + suffix
        break
```

I like to break stuff ;)

Answer (score -4):

If I understand the question (that being how to add the u only for a Q/O prefix) you end up with something like this:

```
for letter in prefix:
     word = letter
     if letter in ["O","U"]:
        word += "u"
     print word . suffix
```

Comment: I get a run-time error with this .. did this work for you when you ran it?

Comment: "." is not a concatenation operator in python.

Comment: Be a bit lucid and delete your answer